# Unity scripts not works after restarting the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I also have the following problem, I start the game in play mode and when I press the button to restart the scene, the scripts no longer work. They are not disabled, nothing.

Hello. I also have the following problem, I start the game in play mode and when I press the button to restart the scene, the scripts no longer work. They are not disabled, nothing.

YouTube video: https://youtu.be/OD9KCmGuZDg

Comment: Any error? same unity version? Add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No errors. Every time I restart or change the scene the scripts stop working and I have to exit and re-enter the game to get it working again

Comment: Add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I don't know though how to add this because this is a unity and just code maybe can't solve the problem.

Comment: Only 1 script not working or all scripts?

Comment: any usage of `DontDestroyOnLoad` / `static`s and maybe stuff loosing references to things that got destroyed on scene reload?

Comment: it has nothing to do with OnDestroy. All scripts in the game freeze, so to speak, when I change or re-enter a scene

Answer (score 0):

I used to have an issue similar. In your restart script, make sure you set Time.timeScale back to one after restarting. Otherwise, the game will still be paused even after you restart.